# json-schema-faker including extra url in results

Tags: javascript, json

I'm setting up json-schema-faker to create some mock data for a project.

When I generate the data it includes an extra bit with the following as the last item in the generated data.

```
"id": "http://json-schema.org/schema#"
```

Here is my schema (from a file named 'mockDataSchema.js'):

```
exports.schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "users": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 2,
      "maxItems": 2,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "number",
            "unique": true,
            "minimum": 1
          },
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "faker": "name.firstName"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "faker": "name.lastName"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "string",
            "faker": "internet.email"
          }
        },
        "required": ["id", "firstName", "lastName", "email"]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["users"]
}
```

The code to generate the data ('generate-mock-data.js'):

```
var jsf = require('json-schema-faker')
var schema = require('./mockDataSchema')
var fs = require('fs')
var chalk = require('chalk')

const json = JSON.stringify(jsf(schema))
console.log(json)
fs.writeFile('./src/api/db.json', json, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(chalk.red(err))
  } else {
    console.log(chalk.green('Mock data generated.'))
  }
})
```

Add the data that is returned:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "users": [
      { "id": 25582343, "firstName": "Brycen", "lastName": "Dickens", "email": "Angelica_Jakubowski@hotmail.com" },
      { "id": 39817508, "firstName": "Marisa", "lastName": "Terry", "email": "Arlo.Hermann0@yahoo.com" }
    ]
  },
  "id": "http://json-schema.org/schema#"
}
```

I've been unable to determine why it includes the "id": "http://json-schema.org/schema#"

I would like to get rid of that line. I'll be using this with 'json-server' to provide a mock api and it chokes on that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.

```
exports.schema = {
```

was causing jscon-schema-faker to interpret '.schema' as part of the schema.

Changed to

```
module.exports = {
```

and the trailing schema link wnet away.